# Resource.Loading not detecting

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiNjW.png)

what's the error?

I'm using kotlin in android studio

Comment: You need to give us more details, what's the resource class ? Where are you getting it from (import) ? Also avoid using screen and copy your code directly in the post

Comment: package com.example.newmobileapp.util

sealed class Resource<T> (
        val data: T?=null,
        val message: String?=null
){
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String): Resource<T>(message = message)
    class Loading<T>: Resource<T>()
}

Comment: Please update your original post.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have imported a wrong `Resource` class or your `Resource` class does not have that property. First you should check your import for your `Resource` class.